# Creating a JPanel Background

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border, layout-manager

I just got back into coding, so my apologies for my noobines. I'm trying to create a simple program, with a menu where there is a background, and then in the center is a border, containing two buttons. I've sadly had no idea on how to make my JPanel (background), the background, and have my JPanel (main), just in the center not interfering with anything else.

Here is my code:

```
package me.niknea.supremeinvasion.menus;


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Created by Niknea on 7/20/14.
 */
public class Login extends JFrame{

   JPanel background, main;


   JButton loginButton, registerButton;

   public Login(){

        super("SupremeInvasion");

        selector();
        this.setSize(300, 300);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }//end SimpleGui

    public void selector(){
       main = new JPanel();
       background = new JPanel();

       registerButton = new JButton("Register");
       loginButton = new JButton("Login");

        main.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        background.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

       main.add(registerButton);
       main.add(loginButton);
        main.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        main.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
        background.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        background.add(main, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(background);
    }


}
```

And a picture of how it looks : http://gyazo.com/e19aa2f86a53ae08e59218e958b766fa, as you can see, the buttons arent centered, nor is the background cyan with only the center being gray with the buttons.

Thanks again,

Niknea.

Comment: share the snapshot of your design and mention where did you stuck.

Comment: The background JPanel shod have a layout manager of BorderLayout and main JPanel could benefit from a different layout manager as well

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 2):

> the buttons arent centered

If you want the buttons horizontally and vertically centered the easiest way is to use a `GridBagLayout` on the "backgroundPanel".

> nor is the background cyan with

That is because the "main" panel completely covers the background panel. Make the "main" panel opaque by using:

```
main.setOpaque(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it again after removing below line from your code.

```
background.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

and simply add `main` panel in `background` panel.

```
background.add(main);
```

For further reading, please follow *Swing Tutorial* on [How to Use Various Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html)

---

Is this what you want?

[image]

Comment: Yes, however now the main panel isn't centered, it's north like in your picture.

Comment: OK you want it center vertically as well. Let me change.

Answer (score 0):

You must set BorderLayout to background. It's default is FlowLayout. You can set a BorderLayout to the panel background and setPreferredSize to the panel main.

```
background.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Comment: I did, I created a new JPanel, called background for this purpose, with almost the same code, yet it dosent work.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot recommend using `GridBagLayout` manager. It has many drawbacks.

I have created two examples with `MigLayout` and `GroupLayout`.

I am not sure whether the user really needs a separate panel for
the two buttons. (People often seem to think that we need 
a panel for such a task when in reality it is not needed.)
But nevertheless I have placed to buttons into a panel and
centered the panel on the window.

**Solution with MigLayout**

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class CenteredButtons extends JFrame {

    public CenteredButtons() {

        initUI();

        setSize(300, 250);
        setTitle("Centered buttons");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout("center, center"));

        JPanel cpnl = new JPanel();
        cpnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        cpnl.add(new JButton("Register"));
        cpnl.add(new JButton("Login"));

        add(cpnl);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CenteredButtons ex = new CenteredButtons();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Centered buttons]

**Solution with GroupLayout**

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class CenteredButtons2 extends JFrame {

    public CenteredButtons2() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Centered buttons");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
        pane.setLayout(gl);

        JPanel cpnl = new JPanel();
        cpnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        cpnl.add(new JButton("Register"));
        cpnl.add(new JButton("Login"));

        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(1, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(cpnl, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(1, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(1, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(cpnl, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(1, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();        
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CenteredButtons2 ex = new CenteredButtons2();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```